# For loop confusion, why isn't this looping?

Tags: java, for-loop

So I have a method in which I pass an ArrayList to the idea of this method is to take the input and split each set of matching strings into their own separate list. Here some pseudo code.

```
Array = (a,a,a,b,c,d,d,e,e,e,e,e,f,f,s)
```

So what I want this algo to do is to split this array into a 2D array with equal elements. Like this.

```
A[0][] = (a,a,a)
A[1][] = (b)
A[2][] = (c)
A[3][] = (d,d)
A[4][] = (e,e,e,e,e)
A[5][] = (f,f)
A[6][] = (s)
```

So what I tried to do is put it in a for loop that check an extra element ahead to see if it NOT equal to, then it knows t

```
 int equalStringGroupIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for(int first = 0, second = 0 ; input.get(first).equals(input.get(second)); second++){
        equalStringGroups[equalStringGroupIndex][i] = input.get(second);
        i++;
        //This if statment checks the element ahead then equals first = second, But when it jumps back to the top of the loop in the debugger it does'nt seem to check it even though in my Watches it's True
        if(!input.get(first).equals(input.get(second + 1))){
            equalStringGroupIndex++;
            i = 0;
            first = second;
        }
    }
```

Why does it not loop after adding the first set of 'a' to the 2D array
Thanks.

UPDATE:
Thanks for the help, I decided to go the HashMap route. Here's what I came up with. It appear's to work.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> countDuplicates(ArrayList<String> input){

    HashMap<String, Integer> duplicates = new HashMap<>();

    //Value init loop, sets all values to 0;
    for (String s : input){
        Integer valueInitVar = 0;
        duplicates.put(s, valueInitVar);
    }

    //Increases the value by 1  each time the same key is encountered;
    for (String s : input){
        Integer tempDuplicateAmount = duplicates.get(s);
        //I could use the '++' operator but I feel ' var += 1' is much nicer to read;
        tempDuplicateAmount += 1;
        duplicates.put(s, tempDuplicateAmount);
    }

    return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: Sorted array of strings

Comment: And why is *what* happening?

Comment: It does not loop after adding the first set of 'a'  to the 2D array

Comment: It is because your condition is then false. `a` does not equal `b` and so it exits. You should use `input.length` or `input.size` for the condition and test accordingly

Comment: but where "first = second" on my debugger it jumps to the top of the For loop and checks the condition again, if they are both pointing to the same index number of the Array list it is the same element. How is the same elements value not equal to itself?

Comment: You add one to `second`, thus `second` is pointing to a different index

Comment: Hint: your real problem is that you wrote so complicated code. You are stopping your loop to early; but the fact that your code is so hard to read simply obfuscates that.

Comment: I used "second + 1" NOT "second += 1"

Comment: Correct. You are adding one to the index you are checking. Once `a,a,a` is added, you are on the third `a`, and when you check the next index, you are at `b`, which does not equal, so it enters the if statement and then goes back to the top of the loop. Your `first` variable is now `a` and your second is now `b`. Try `first = second+1`. That may be a quick fix.

Comment: But, your code will still break because of your conditional.

Comment: Is this an assignment?  It doesn't really make sense to store an array of identical Strings.  Why not just store a map where the keys are the distinct strings and the value is an integer representing how many times it occurs.  This code is overly complex but even a simplified version will be more complicated than using a map.  In addition, your input doesn't need to be sorted for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something else:

```
List<List<Whatever>> splitSame(List<Whatever> input) {
  List<List<Whatever>> rv = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Whatever> currentValues = new ArrayList<>(); 
  Whatever lastChecked = input.get(0);
  for (Whatever what : input) {
    if (lastChecked.equals(what)) {
      currentValues.add(what);
    } else {
      rv.put(currentValues);
      currentValues = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    lastChecked = what;
  }
  rv.put(currentValues);
  return rv;
```

The point is: you can easily walk over you one input list to collect equal objects within sub lists. And in the end, you just pull those together.

I am sure some java8 guru could rewrite the above using streams into something even more concise and less complicated.

No need for additional two-dim arrays complexity here at all!

( hint: code just written down, might contain typos, and there is a subtle bug in there when the *last* element is different, but: it is meant to give you an idea how to do things differently; further details left to the reader )

Comment: Definitely the better way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Where, I have to admit, the List and ListList somehow looks scary; making the whole thing harder to read than it actually is. Probably that is really one of those cases where some stream magic really trumpets "old school".

Comment: I don't find it scary, but if you are coming from an "old school" point of view it may be a little overwhelming. With a thorough read through it is easily understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to stick to doing it this way, I suggest changing your conditional in the for loop to be `second < input.size (or length)`

```
int equalStringGroupIndex = 0;
int i = 0;

for(int first = 0, second = 0 ; second < input.size(); second++){
    equalStringGroups[equalStringGroupIndex][i] = input.get(second);
    i++;

    if(!input.get(first).equals(input.get(second + 1))){
        equalStringGroupIndex++;
        i = 0;
        first = second+1;
    }
}
```

This way, you are looping ONLY through the array, no out of bounds exceptions there.

I also changed your `first = second` to `first = second+1` because once you have found they are not equal, you should set the first index to the the next one and by doing `first = second` you are not.